# Finding if current date is an alternate date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have to implement a subscription where users can choose to subscribe his products which will get delivered to him on each `alternate` from the date he subscribed or with a `Two Day Gap` from the subscribed date.

```
 //Sample Data
 [
   { 
      "subscribed_on": ISODate("2017-01-01T08:15:39.736Z"),
      "_id" : 1, 
      "customer" : "jon doe", 
      "type": "alternate"
   },
   {
      "subscribed_on": ISODate("2017-01-02T08:15:39.736Z"),
      "_id" : 1, 
      "customer" : "Doe John", 
      "type": "Two Day Gap"
   },
   {
      subscribed_on: ISODate("2017-01-02T08:15:39.736Z"),
      "_id" : 1, 
      "customer" : "Foo Name", 
      "type": "alternate"
   }
 ]
```

Now for each day I have to query to find the list of the customers which have the delivery for today's date.

How can I aggregate so that I can calculate if the current date is the `alternate` date or lies in `two-day gap`?

To simplify the query for alternate I can check if the current date is `even or odd` and will query the date opposite it. Like if the current date is `1st Jan` which is `odd` I can query to find the date which is `even` for `alternate` subscription query. **Is this correct efficient  way for finding alternate date?**

What will be the current way to find the subscription for `Two Day Gap` type?

Comment: You might loop over the array and see if the date part of *subscribed_on* is equal to the date part of `new Date().toISOString()`. Then check if *type* is "alternate" or not. Note that using UTC based dates might have apparent discrepancies with local dates due to time zones.